# What approach should I follow for report SSRS , SSIS ETL and Data warehouse

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis, ssrs-2008, data-warehouse

I'm working on SSRS.Actually I'm new to this.We have a OLTP database in which we have created stored procedure for each report.These stored procedures are used to create DataSet in BI solution to run the report.

Now we were asked to go through SSIS process ( ETL ) and Data Warehouse concept and all reports will now be running through these two approach.

So my doubt is:

1) As per my knowledge in SSIS , we have to create a new database and new tables for each report.Through packages (which include ETL process) we will insert all data into each tables and finally will fetch report data from these table directly.
This approach speed up data retrieval process because data is already calculated for every reports and do not need to design Data Warehouse.

Am I right?

2) Do we really need to run all reports through SSIS and Data Warehouse approach i.e. how can i judge which report need to run through SSIS and Data Warehouse approach  OR can continue running report with OLTP system.

3) Any best article link for SSIS and Data warehouse concept

4) Do I have to first create SSIS packages before designing Data warehouse.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) I'm not sure you want a table per report.  I guess you might end up with this if non of your reports used the same fields. When I hear data warehouse, I think dimensional model/star schema.  The benefit of a star schema is that it simplifies the data model and reduces the amount of joins you might have to go through to get the data you need, optimizing for data retrieval.

2) The answer to this question depends on your goals. Many companies with a data warehouse try to do all non-real-time reporting out of their data warehouse or an ODS to reduce the load on the production OLTP system. If optimized reliability and speed of report delivery is the goal, then test query speeds, data integrity, and accuracy and decide if a data warehouse with ETL provides a better experience (and if that justifies the monitoring and maintenance required for a data warehouse).

3) For data warehouse concepts, try the [Kimball Group](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-core-concepts/).  For SSIS, start with [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx) and make sure to visit the SSIS Package Essentials page.

4)You should design your data warehouse before you build SSIS packages. You might have to make a few tweaks as you get into the ETL process, but you generally know what you want to end up with (your DW design) and use SSIS to get the data to that desired end state.

Comment: +1  Just adding that if you don't want a new table per report, you definitely don't want a database per report!

Comment: actually i have downloaded a AdventureWorksDW database and when i go through tables in this database it starts with Dim... and Fact...
So when i create new database and tables for each reports how can i decide which table have Dim and Fact prefix.

Comment: Read the info from the Kimball group that I posted above. This is part of dimensional modeling. Facts include measurements of some kind (counts, amounts, etc.).  Dimensions are about a noun (customer, store, etc.) rather than an action.